# REST Naming convention for GET List and GET Paginated

Tags: rest, restful-url

I have to create two endpoints to the same entity that one return a entity list and the second return a paginated result (that contains the list and totalPages, pageNumber, totalPerPage, etc).

**Like:**

1. Make a query according to filters and the return can be big (so it returns with pagination)

> *GET /entity?filter1=x&filter2=y returns a Paginated Result*

2. Make a query according to some parameters that returns a couple
   records in a List

> *GET /entity?param=x&param=y returns a List*

**Problem:**

I can't use the same path to do that. So what is the naming convention for that?

something like: "GET /entity" and "GET /entity/page" ?

I did not find in: https://restfulapi.net/resource-naming/

Answer (score 1):

REST doesn't care what spelling conventions you use for your resource identifiers.  You can use any spelling you like - best to be consistent with your local conventions, and that the chosen spelling is preferred by some of your human users (writers of documentation, operators reading through access logs, etc).

It may help to adopt the perspective of your domain experts - are these two different reports that have distinct names?  Are they used by different consumers?  projects with different code names? releases with different dates? schemas with different versions?

A common problem in designing a resource identifier: not having a clear understanding of what the actual resource (document) itself.

If you can't come up with anything sensible, fall back to the difference that you understand.

```
GET /entity/list?...
GET /entity/page?...
```

Again, also fine.